# Passing Message to background thread causes corruption

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to run all of my service requests on a background thread. To do this, I make a `ExecutorService` and redirect all calls to the main handler (`handleMessage`) to a handler on the new thread (`handleMessageHelper`):

```
ExecutorService background = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

//handles messages from client
class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
        background.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handleMessageHelper(msg); //actually handles the request
            }
        });
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

However, somehow the `msg` is getting corrupted between when the new `Runnable` is created, and when the `run()` function is called. Any way to prevent this?

Comment: Could you describe the symptoms that lead you believe the message is corrupted? Meanwhile, clone your message: `final Message pass = Message.obtain( <background thread> ); pass.copyFrom( msg );` then use `pass` in your `run()`.

Comment: Is that last `super.handleMessage(msg);` necessary? What's its purpose?

Comment: when I print `msg.what`, I get `1` (as expected) when the Runnable is created, but `0` when `run()` is called. I will try your suggestions though

Comment: removing `super.handleMessage(msg)` does not fix it, but making a copy does

Comment: I also noticed that `IncomingHandler` has a warning that says `This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur`

Comment: Please show how the client message is send to IncomingHandler.

Comment: @woojoo666, so the cloning works? Problem solved?